# Configure HTTPS : AWS elastic beanstalk application

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

I am trying to configure HTTPS for my elastic beanstalk application which is pointed to my domain (say `sample.com`),for that i've tried the following steps.

1.Obtained an SSL certificate from the AWS certificate manager.

2.Attached the SSL certificate ID in load balancer configuration

My  calls to https not working but the http is working fine.

I've referred this question [HTTPS not working (on AWS Elastic Beanstalk based site)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589413/https-not-working-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-based-site) but i got confusing with the answer especially with the `name of the certificate`.

Currently my load balancer security group have the following rules.

[image]

**Update**

When i access the domain with https (eg:`https:\\www.mysite.com`) i can able to see the website but the ssl error is shown in the title bar.

[image]

Comment: "My calls to https not working" - what is the error that you get? And what is your client?

Comment: When i access my domain like this way `https:\\www.mysite.com` i can see the webpage but  not secure error is show in domain bar.

Comment: @yishaiz i've updated my question

Comment: You should be able to see more details in the browser for the reason of the "Not Secure". Try clicking on the "Not Secure", or to check if there is a warning in the chrome devtools.

Comment: Your connection is not secure thats the only detailed error.

Comment: After you click the "Not Secure"? At chrome you should have a "Details" link in that window.